# OOP PHP Pseudo Multiple Inheritance - Base classes having same functions

Tags: php

I'm kinda new in PHP OOP thing, I don't know how to call it but it looks like Multiple Inheritance to me.

```
class A {
    function doSomething() {
        echo "Just doing something!";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function doSometing() {
        echo "Just do it!";
    }
}

class C extends B {
    function runDoSomething() {
        print_r($this->doSomething);
    }
}

$c = new C();
$c->runDoSomething(); // This will print class B doSomething() "Just do it!"
```

So my first question is, this a bad code? since PHP doesn't support Multiple Inheritance and parent Class kinda overriding each other when there is a same function.

Second question, is there another way to call class A doSomething() function rather than instantiating a parent Class inside a subclass function?

```
class C extends B {
    function runDoSomething() {
        $a = new A();
        print_r($a->doSomething); // This will print class A doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is bad design depends on the use case for it. Sometimes it's necessary. If you want to use class A's method in class C, you should extend class A instead of class B. Alternatively, you could create a new method in class B, something like: `function doSomethingOriginal() { return parent::doSomething(); }` and call that method from class C instead. If it's all your code, you could look into using traits for some common methods. What you should use and how you should implement it depends 100% on the actual use case.

Comment: That is _not_ multiple inheritance! Multiple inheritance means that you inherit from multiple classes, not from a class that inherits from another class and so on, those two things are different. From the inheriting class this is clean, it sees only one parent class offering methods. If those were inherited or overwrite inherited methods is another thing. Sometimes it does make sense, for example if you define a default method and later, in the inheriting classes want to implement a very special case. Then there is no reason to declare the parent class abstract and implement it in all classes.